# Where can I learn about programming my Jail broken iOS device?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I'd like to do some R&D pushing the boundaries of iOS devices. Is there a how-to guide or private API documentation?

Is there a Stack Exchange site for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Stack Exchange proposal but it's lacking support:

> [...]for iOS developers who require
>   help and advice when using
>   undocumented iOS APIs. Developers who
>   discover private iOS APIs and need a
>   place to document them.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/ios-private-apis

Comment: Note that the linked proposal is now closed.