# Getting started with jailbroken iOS development?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, development

What do I need to code on a jailbroken iOS device?

I think I've already got all of the programs that I need - Xcode 4.3 (and iOSOpenDev), the iOS 5 SDK, theos, ldid and dpkg.

Comment: Actually there is a specific stack exchange site proposal for jailbreak development discussion. [See this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/2269/3117) and if it interests you, follow the link and add your support.

Comment: That link links to this link: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/ios-jailbreaking-development?phase=commitment&conf=1

Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cydia FAQ is probably the best source of information on this topic. See http://cydia.saurik.com/faq/developing.html. Here’s an excerpt:

> Q: Where do I get started with developing for jailbroken iOS?
>
> A: It helps to know something about developing for normal iOS. You might also check out [the iPhone Dev Wiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/).

The wiki it points to has several “Quick Start” articles: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Main_Page#Quick_start

Comment: That links back to the iPhoneDevWiki, which is incomplete and out-dated. :/ Thanks anyway, though.

Comment: @BenHooper You’re right; there are pages on there that mention iOS 4.3 without mentioning iOS 5. But does it really make that much of a difference? Whether you’re developing for iOS 4 or 5, it’s still the same development workflow.

Comment: Yes, you are right that it would involve the same workflow, but when you wish to develop tweaks that target very specific parts of the iOS 5 UIKit, it does matter.

Comment: @BenHooper Yes, but those specific parts aren’t jailbreak-specific, and are thoroughly documented by Apple, e.g. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/_index.html I’d suggest to use the iPhone Dev Wiki to get jailbreak-specific info, and use Apple’s official developer docs for everything else. Hope this helps!